# How to send error message from salesforce to third party within response

Tags: integration

We have done integration from third party to salesforce, to be specific with Tibco. We have a webservice class in salesforce which is being invoked from Tibco and we send xml file with parameters.

For some parameters my webservice class fails.How can I send back error message from salesforce to Tibco.

Comment: Its too broad to answer. You will have to make changes to the Webservice class by handling the errors and send them the error in a mutually agreed format!

Comment: Hey Amit thanks for suggestion. Will it be possible for you to provide some sample code regarding modifications in webservice class. Also i do not understand how exactly mutual agreed format be done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the parameter you return. For eg. 
`WebService static TestMethod (String x, String y, Date z)
    {
        if(x== '' || x== null)

        {
            RespSP.status= 'Failed';
            RespSP.statusMessage ='X is missing';
            return RespSP; 
        }
        else if(y== '' || y== null)

        {
            RespSP.status= 'Failed';
            RespSP.statusMessage ='y is missing';
            return RespSP; 
        }
        else if(z== null)

        {
            RespSP.status= 'Failed';
            RespSP.statusMessage ='z is missing';
            return RespSP; 
        }`

Comment: Thanks Shailesh. Just curious to know, how is that different from standard respinse salesforce would send back to calling party.

Comment: In this case, we have used a wrapper class and defined separate responses for separate conditions customised. If you could post your code, I may suggest you a better answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hey thanks, using your sample code I was able to write a good piece for myslf, i havnt chkd it yet. Appreciate ur help.